# How to save ODE solution only at the last step while using Callbacks in Julia

Tags: julia, ode, differentialequations.jl

I am solving the following ode, using Julia. The code I am using is as follows:

```
   using DelimitedFiles
   using LinearAlgebra 
   using Random
   using Distributions
   using DifferentialEquations
   using Plots

   N = 100
   σ, a, J, K = 10.0, 1.0,1.0,1.0
   ω = zeros(N); 

   function heaviside(x::Real)
        return x >= 0.0 ? 1.0 : 0.0
   end


   function rhs(du,u,p,t)

    u1 = @view u[1:N]
    du1 = @view du[1:N]
    u2 = @view u[N+1:2*N]
    du2 = @view du[N+1:2*N]
 
    σ,a,J,K=p

   for i in 1:N
    du1[i]=(1/N)*sum(j->((u1[j]-u1[i])*(1+J*cos(u2[j]-u2[i]))-sign(u1[j]-u1[i])),1:N)
    
    du2[i]=(ω[i]) + (K/N)* sum(j->(sin(u2[j]-u2[i])*(1-(u1[j]-u1[i])^2/ 
  σ^2)*heaviside(σ - abs((u1[j]-u1[i])))),1:N)
  end


    return du 

  end


  ti=0
  tf=500
  tt=0.75*tf
  tspan = (ti, tf)  # Assuming you want to integrate from 0 to T
  dts=0.25
  vector_t=tt:dts:tf
  p=[σ,a,J,K]
  Random.seed!(123)
  u0= [(rand() * 8.0 - 4.0, rand() * (2.0 * π) - π) for j in 1:N]
  u0=vcat([x[1] for x in u0], [x[2] for x in u0]);

  prob = ODEProblem(rhs,u0, tspan,p);


      # For making mean_u1 zero
      function condition(u,t,integrator)
       t == integrator.t
      end

      function affect!(integrator)

      u1_mean = mean(integrator.u[1:N])
      integrator.u[1:N] .-= u1_mean
      end

      cbd = DiscreteCallback(condition, affect!)

    ##################################
  saved_values2= SavedValues(Float64,ComplexF64)
   function saver2(u,t,integrator)
       _pp=u[1:N]
       _qq=u[N+1:2*N]
      out2= mean((_pp).*exp.((_qq)*1im))
   end
 cb2 = SavingCallback(saver2, saved_values2,saveat=tt:dts:tf) 
 ###################################

  ###################################

   saved_values4= SavedValues(Float64,Float64)
 function saver4(u,t,integrator)
       duc=rhs(zeros(size(u)),u,integrator.p,t)
        _pp=duc[1:N]
       _qq=duc[N+1:2*N]
    out4= mean(sqrt.(((_pp).^2)+((_qq).^2)))
 end
cb4 = SavingCallback(saver4, saved_values4,saveat=tt:dts:tf)
 #####################################

   cbs = CallbackSet(cbd, cb2,cb4);

    @time sol= solve(prob, Tsit5(),reltol=1e-6,maxiters=1e20, callback = cbs,saveat= 
      [tf]);


      sizeof(sol)

      saved_values4.saveval
      print(mean(saved_values4.saveval));



       Z1=saved_values2.saveval;
       vel=saved_values4.saveval;
```

So in the above code I am making the mean of u1 variable zero after each integration step using DiscreteCallback, and then I am using SavingCallback to store two measures Z1 and vel from the integration within the time range tt:dts:tf, therefore the in SavingCallback function I have added the saveat=tt:dts:tf.
So, I don't need the whole solution given by sol after the integration and only need the solution at the last time. That's why I have used the saveat=[tf] there. But even after doing this the integration is saving the solution for all the steps. So can anyone suggest me why this is happening and also how to overcome this, because saving the sol taking much space and making my machine very slow.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to your problem, when you want the `SavingCallback` to only save at the last time step, then you also have to use only this last time step at the `saveat` of the `SavingCallback`, not (only) of the `solve` command. Currently you provide the `SavingCallback` with the instruction to save at `tt:dts:tf`

Comment: with small value of N and small time span the results are easily reproducible. I have changed N to 100 and total time to 500.  
As I want to save the quantities from saving callback from tt:dts:tf , so I have used that time range there. After using that there is no need for me to the variable sol, so I wanted there only the last solution.

Comment: I am confused what you want. Please provide a _minimal_ example of your problem, as this would also make it more clear what your problem is.

Comment: I only want the measuments Z1 and vel in the time range tt:dts:tf from the ode solver. So it is being done by the SavingCallback function with the saveat=tt:dts:tf. Now the solution of the ode is of no need for me after the integration is completed. So I just saved the sol of the ode at the last time step. So the size of sol should be here (200,1) if I take N=100. 
But what I am getting is that the size of sol is (200,p), where p is the total integration step. And it is thus taking unnecessary memory.

Comment: Alternatively to the ```saveat```. You can also use ```save_on=false, save_start=false, save_end=true``` to only save the end point. Please read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to see how you can write minimal examples of your problem. Then other people could help you with your problem quicker and also run your code to test it.